# CA1033 with Properties

Tags: c#, code-analysis, stylecop

When I run code analysis (VS2013) with the 'Microsoft Managed Recommend Rules' rule set, the only warnings I get for my class library are of type [CA1033: 'Interface methods should be callable by child types'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182153.aspx). But I don't understand the rule in this situation:

```
/// An object that has a chemical formula
public interface IChemicalFormula
{ 
    /// The chemical formula of the object
    ChemicalFormula ChemicalFormula {get;}       
}

public class ChemicalFormula: IChemicalFormula
{         
    ChemicalFormula IChemicalFormula.ChemicalFormula
    {
        get { return this; }
    }
}
```

The docs recommends making a protected method with the same name so that deriving types can access it, but you cannot name a method the same as the enclosing type. They also recommend making the class sealed, but I don't want it to be sealed in this case. Is this a time just to ignore this rule, or is there an appropriate way to handle it?

**EDIT**

To add clarification why the class/interface is designed this way, I have another class, `Peptide` that contains a `IChemicalFormula[]` array to store modifications. Not every modification necessarily derives directly from `ChemicalFormula`, but they need to implement the `IChemicalFormula` interface. Therefore, if I modify an instance of a peptide withsome molecule (H2O for example), then `ChemicalFormula` class needs to also implement `IChemicalFormula`.

Comment: So `IChemicalFormula` represents a type that _has_ a `ChemicalFormula`?  And a `ChemicalFormula` _has a_ `ChemicalFormula`?  Sounds like you could choose better names and solve your problem.

Comment: Firstly, it seems a little weird to have your a property on your interface which returns a type of a class which implements that interface...

Comment: @VP I have a lot of extension methods for IChemicalFormula, so that is why the ChemicalFormula class uses the interface

Comment: I'm a still confused by what you mean. Extension methods are great, but my point is that if you have an interface `A`, and a concrete class `B` which implements `A`, that interface `A` should know nothing about the class type `B` which may or may not implement it.

Comment: @DStanley A chemical formula of course has a chemical formula, it is itself and that is why I return `this`

Comment: Having a property which just returns `this` is 100% useless in my opinion. If you already have access to the instance, whether it by by the class name `ChemicalFormula` or the interface `IChemicalFormula`, you should not ever try to grab the instance you already have by calling a property which is just returning `this`.

Comment: Something that would make much more sense is to have a `ChemicalSolution` class which does not implement `IChemicalFormula`, but instead has a property which returns an `IChemicalFormula`. That allows a you to ask the solution for it's formula...

Comment: As a side note, look into explicit interface implementation and make sure it fits your needs here. See more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @VP the main reason for this design is for multiple inheritance. Consider `class A` and `class B : A, IChemicalFormula`,I want class `B` to be able to use all the extension methods i have for IChemicalFormula without necessarily deriving from ChemicalFormula.

Comment: @Moop "A chemical formula of course has a chemical formula"  Does it? That seems like a circular definition.  So in that same method would a `Car` _have a_ `Car`? No, it would have parts, a Make, a Model, etc.  Having a property that just returns itself seems pointless.

Comment: @DStanley I think you twisted the analogy a little. Think of DNA, most people think of it as a string of Nucleotides and the end user approaches that object like a `Nucleotide[]` more so than a chemical formula (which it is, albeit a very large formula). But it still has the property of being a chemical formula because it is a chemical formula. It is given a different name because it is used in a different context. The order of the Nucleotides in DNA is more important than its chemical formula. But that doesn't mean DNA is not a chemical formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the description of the rule:

> Consider a base type that explicitly implements a public interface
>   method. A type that derives from the base type can access the
>   inherited interface method only through a reference to the current
>   instance (this in C#) **that is cast to the interface**. If the derived
>   type re-implements (explicitly) the inherited interface method, the
>   base implementation can no longer be accessed. The call through the
>   current instance reference will invoke the derived implementation;
>   this causes recursion and an eventual stack overflow.

I think you should consider evaluating the usage of this property. A good example where TDD could be used to figure out the interface. There are some possible usages (and some invalid ones) below. I am not yet sure what you intend to achieve by looking at those.

In your example, let's say another class, `NewChemicalForumla` is derived from `ChemicalForumula`, and references `ChemicalFormula`, what does that mean?

```
public class NewChemicalFormula: ChemicalFormula
{         
    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", ChemicalFormula.GetType());       // Compile error
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", this.ChemicalFormula.GetType());  // Effectively same as above, compile error
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", ((IChemicalFormula)this).ChemicalFormula.GetType()); // Works, is that what you intend?
    }
}
```

Now from outside the class, there are two possibilities:

1. When you have a handle to a derived class:

   ```
   new NewChemicalFormula().ChemicalFormula.GetType() // Error
   ```

   or

   ```
   // This works, is that what you intend to achieve?
   ((IChemicalFormula)new NewChemicalFormula()).ChemicalFormula.GetType()
   ```
2. When you have a handle to the IChemicalFormula already. In this case, ChemicalFormula seems redundant:

   ```
   IChemicalFormula formula = new NewChemicalFormula();
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", formula.GetType());                 // Works, returns NewChemicalFormula
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", formula.ChemicalFormula.GetType()); // Works, returns NewChemicalFormula
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", formula.ChemicalFormula.Method());  // Compile error
   ```

`formula.ChemicalFormula.Method()` leads to an error because you must cast it to `NewChemicalFormula` before you can use `Method()`. Just because the property returns `this` doesn't help solve this problem.

So the FXCop warning is worth considering, and evaluating the design.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I think what I am going to do is just make `ChemicalFormula` sealed after all, it will avoid these issues you bring up.

Comment: @Moop You don't necessarily have to make it sealed. It is best to write code how you think this property will be used and see if it solves the issue you are trying to solve, and if there are any alternatives. I do not yet know what purpose this property will serve since it just returns the instance itself, i.e. `abc.ChemicalFormula == abc`, isn't it? If it is, then why need `.ChemicalFormula`?

Comment: @Moop sealed will just hide the problem in your design. You have to rethink what you actually want to achieve because what you have above doesn't make sense as many others explained it.